# How to zoom to a country by name in an Android application

Tags: android, google-maps

How to zoom to a country by name in an Android application(google map)? IF I get a coutry name Ireland then the map location to the Ireland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Geocoder API to fetch the location based on the country name and then animate the map camera to that position:

```
try {
    List<Address> address = new Geocoder(this).getFromLocationName("Ireland", 1);
    if (address == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Not found");
    } else {
        Address loc = address.get(0);
        Log.e(TAG, loc.getLatitude() + " " + loc.getLongitude());
        LatLng pos = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude())
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 14));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1 Get location by country name

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(<your context>);  
    List<Address> addresses;
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(<String address>, 1);
    if(addresses.size() > 0) {
        double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
        double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
    }
```

2 Zoom to current location

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10));
```